# Having one element with two different definition/type in XSD 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have to write an XML schema (in XSD 1.0) to validate a given document.

In this document, there is an element called `box` that either:

- has **two required attributes**, `name` and `weight` and some other optional one, **no content**
- has **one required attribute**, `name`, **no other attributes**, and **several element as content** (including `box` elements).

*For example:*

```xml
<box name="box_1"> <!-- type 2 -->
    <box name="box_2"> <!-- type 2 -->
        <box name="box_3" weight="10" height="5" /> <!-- type 1 -->
        <box name="box_4" weight="15" /> <!-- type 1 -->
    </box>
    <box name="box_5"> <!-- type 2 -->
        <box name="box_6" weight="21" /> <!-- type 1 -->
    </box>
</box>
<box name="box_7" weight="21" /> <!-- type 1 -->
```

The issue is that:

- I cannot define `box` with two different types (xmllint does not recognise which type is used and invalidate any `box` that doesn't have the attribute `weight`)
- I cannot add `<xs:attributes>` in a `<xs:choice>`
- I cannot use `<xs:alternative>` because I have to use XSD 1.0
- I cannot make `weight` optional, it has to be required
- I cannot modify the given xml document

This, for example, does not work:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="closet">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="box" type="TboxComplex" />
        <xs:element name="box" type="TboxSimple" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TboxComplex">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="box" type="TboxComplex" />
            <xs:element name="box" type="TboxSimple" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="name"   type="xs:string"  use="required" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TboxSimple">
    <xs:attribute name="name"   type="xs:string"  use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="weight" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:integer" use="optional" />
</xs:complexType>
```

```bash
> xmllint --schema room.xsd room.xml 
room.xml:9: element box: Schemas validity error : Element 'box', attribute 'weight': The attribute 'weight' is not allowed.`
room.xml:9: element box: Schemas validity error : Element 'box', attribute 'height': The attribute 'height' is not allowed.
room.xml:9: element box: Schemas validity error : Element 'box': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( box ).
```

Could you help me find a way to define that element without needing to change the xml document or switch to XSD 1.1, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You won't be able to achieve it in XSD 1.0. On the other hand, it is very easy in XSD 1.1 that is available since May 2012, i.e. more than a decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD 1.0 is not capable of defining this constraint. You will need to use some other validation technology such as XSD 1.1, RelaxNG, or Schematron; or you might be able to do it with XSD 1.0 if you are prepared to add `xsi:type` attributes to your XML instance.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for clarifying that it is indeed not possible.